# In Oracle Apex 5 I want to link to an Interactive Report and set a filter RequestID = #RequestID#

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to link a column from an Interactive Report to another Interactive Report in Apex 5. I want to set the filter in the later one with a value from the first one. I used a column of type Link then clicked on Target button to set the page number like this:

[image: Here's the values I used]

It doesn't work. I read there are other ways, I could use an URL link and build the URL to pass the parameters using a package but if I used this, how can I bind it to the link?

Comment: I want to create a link in a cell from an Interactive Report to open another page with another Interactive Report then filter the report with an ID. I think I found the solution in the "Expertise Tracker" sample application. I will try tomorrow to see if it does the trick. If it does, I'll provide the solution back here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was causing the filter not to work. I was trying to filter a column of type "link". It doesn't work when it's a "link", but it does when it's "plain text". So now you know. Here's how it's looking...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'll need to specify the operator to be used in the link - documentation:
[Developing Reports > Editing Interactive Reports in Page Designer > Linking to Interactive Reports](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E59726_01/doc.50/e39147/bldapp_rpt003.htm#HTMDB30108)

> *Snippet concerning setting up a link:*
>
> To create a filter, use the following `itemNames` and `itemValues` syntax:
>
> ```
> IR[region static ID]<operator>_<target column alias>
> ```
>
> Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> IR[EMP]C_ENAME:KING
> ```

Meaning that if you want to place a filter on your report where the column `REQUEST_ID` matches a given value, you'd need the equals operator syntax:

```
IREQ_REQUESTID:#REQUEST_ID#
```

However, using

```
IR_REQUESTID:#REQUEST_ID#
```

should also work, as the `EQ` operator is the default operator.

Also consider other issues: do you have more than one IR on the page? You'll need to reference the correct one. Is your generated link correct? Inspect it!

Comment: Thanks Tom, but this is really academic. I got that from Oracle documentation. I'm was looking for how to implement it in APEX GUI.

Comment: @PollusB No problem. It was kind of meant to be "academic". I can't guess the degree of knowledge so I just wanted to add the $0.2. It also didn't dawn on me that the type of column would affect this. Luckily, you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

For me it works like this: 
I created an Item (display only)(source type: null) on the second page with the second IR.

In the first IR in the Column Attributes set a Link Text and the Target and Page number (like you did already). In the Name part put your Item that you just created and for the Value put the column name in which are the values for your filter (like #Request_ID'#).

Then again on the second page with the second IR you will put something like this in the Region Source:

```
select REQUEST_ID,
       REQUEST_NUMBER,
       NAME,
       FIRST_NAME,
       COMPANY,
       COUNTRY,
       TYPE,
       RQ_IS_ARCHIVE,
       RQ_ID_TO
  from REQUEST
where REQUEST_ID = :P20_REQUEST_ID
```

The `:P20_REQUEST_ID` is the Item that you created on that second page.

You passed the value from the Request_ID column from the first page in to the Item on the second page, there you used it then as a condition.

Hope this helps you...

Comment: It's not quite the same though. This method reduces the set of data available to the user. Using the report filter they still have the option to disable or remove the filter.

Comment: Thanks Sara, but you are filtering the data. I want to filter the IR. As said by Tom, it's not the same.